# How to put in Rhythmbox in the sound menu?

Tags: rhythmbox, indicator-sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why were the Rhythmbox controls removed from the sound menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68491/why-were-the-rhythmbox-controls-removed-from-the-sound-menu)

I uninstalled the Banshee, Rhythmbox and installed, but it does not appear in the sound menu, I open Rhytmbox and put on some music and close the Rhytmbox and the music keeps playing, but in the sound menu of Ubuntu does not appear anything Rhytmbox.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a setting in rhythmbox, that is enabled by default in newer ubuntu versions, but needs to be set in older ones. Im not on ubuntu right now, so go to the settings menu and explore around to see if you find it.